# How do you get a smooth surface on cakes?

Tags: baking

I've been making a lot of cakes recently and I've been noticing that tell all have bumps, wrinkles or holes on the surface. Although it doesn't matter much, does any know how to get a *smooth* surface on cakes? Thank-you!

Comment: Do you mean you want the cake to be smooth before or after decoration? What are you using to cover the cake - buttercream, fondant, something else?

Answer (score 2):

**Frost it.**
Most surfaces will be rough when looked at closely enough. Bubbles are introduced when you mix the ingredients together (perhaps more if you use a high-speed machine beater & less if you do it by hand) and as a natural part of baking, from baking soda etc.  That's what makes the cakes more light and airy as opposed to thick.

Answer (score 2):

Turn it over! It's flat on the bottom. You may have to trim the top to get it to lie flat. I do this all the time, especially for layer cakes like Black Forest.